# Unique Dropdownlist is coming for the first page values in Jqgrid

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

Hello Every One!!!
                      I added codes for getting unique dropdownlist in the columns of jqgrid .
Dropdownlist is coming but it is coming for the first page of the jqgrid means that dropdownlist has the unique values of the first page of the jqgrid whereas i need all the unique values of the whole Jqgrid..

Below I am posting my codes...

```
grid = $("#gridId");

        getUniqueNames = function (columnName) {
            var texts = grid.jqGrid('getCol', columnName), uniqueTexts = [],
            textsLength = texts.length, text, textsMap = {}, i;
            for (i = 0; i < textsLength; i++) {
                text = texts[i];
                if (text !== undefined && textsMap[text] === undefined) {
                    // to test whether the texts is unique we place it in the map.
                    textsMap[text] = true;
                    uniqueTexts.push(text);
                }
            }
            return uniqueTexts;
        },
        buildSearchSelect = function (uniqueNames) {
            var values = ":All";
            $.each(uniqueNames, function () {
                values += ";" + this + ":" + this;
            });
            return values;
        },
        setSearchSelect = function (columnName) {
            grid.jqGrid('setColProp', columnName,
            {
                stype: 'select',
                searchoptions: {
                    value: buildSearchSelect(getUniqueNames(columnName)),
                    sopt: ['eq']
                }
            }
        );
        };
```

This function i have called like this...

```
setSearchSelect('extension');
                grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Name',
                    {
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ['cn'],
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                $(elem).autocomplete({
                                    source: getUniqueNames('Name'),
                                    delay: 0,
                                    minLength: 0
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });


                setSearchSelect('username');
                grid.jqGrid('setColProp', 'Name',
                    {
                        searchoptions: {
                            sopt: ['cn'],
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                $(elem).autocomplete({
                                    source: getUniqueNames('Name'),
                                    delay: 0,
                                    minLength: 0
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

In between these two code snippets I am loading data into jqgrid locally using Ajax call.
Any help will be heartely appreciated..
Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I belive getCol will return only currently loaded data from jqgrid (for defined column). 
Because at first you load just first page, autocomplete has no way of knowing unique values of column for more than that!

You will have to either load all pages at once (small dataset) or
fill autocomplete from database.

Comment: Thank you Sir for ur response.I have large dataset of 200000 records ...Then how to fill autocomplete from database..

Comment: Whitch autocomplete control are you using? I would just change
getUniqueNames function and used ajax call in it.

Comment: and what is this  $(elem).autocomplete({